# Python XML Element Tree Filtering

Tags: python, xml

I'm new to python and XML so apologies.

In the XML file I am querying, one of the 'group' categories is called 'Access Points'.

```
 <group id="1">Access Points</group>
```

How can I filter that, and only output that to the screen?

```
for i in tree.iter('ap'):
id=i.attrib

if i.find('group')!=None:
    group=i.find('group').text
else: group=" "   

if i.find('lan_ip')!=None:
    ip=i.find('lan_ip').text
else: ip=" "    

if i.find('lan_mac')!=None:
    mac=i.find('lan_mac').text
else: mac=" "

if i.find('model')!=None:
    model=i.find('model').text
else: model=" "

if i.find('name')!=None:
    name=i.find('name').text
else: name=" "

if i.find('operating_mode')!=None:
    op_mode=i.find('operating_mode').text
else: op_mode=" "

print "\n"+"*"*30
print "#### Details of AP :{}".format(id).ljust(30)
print "*"*30
print "#### Group       :{}".format(group).ljust(30)
print "#### AP Name       :{}".format(name).ljust(30)
print "#### MAC Address   :{}".format(mac).ljust(30)
print "#### IP Address    :{}".format(ip).ljust(30)
print "#### Model         :{}".format(model).ljust(30)
print "#### Operating Mode:{}".format(op_mode).ljust(30)
print "*" * 30
```

**TEST DATA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<amp:amp_ap_list xmlns:amp="http://www.airwave.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.airwave.com amp_ap_list.xsd">
   <ap id="79">
      <altitude>0</altitude>
      <device_category>fat_ap</device_category>
      <client_count>1</client_count>
      <firmware>3.2.0</firmware>
      <fqdn />
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <is_remote_ap>true</is_remote_ap>
      <remote_outer_ip>10.1.1.1</remote_outer_ip>
      <remote_lan_ip>20.20.20.20</remote_lan_ip>
      <lan_ip>10.51.1.191</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:20:A6:55:E6:E1</lan_mac>
      <last_contacted>1350379063</last_contacted>
      <last_reboot>1343644897</last_reboot>
      <mfgr>Proxim</mfgr>
      <model id="44">AP-700</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>ORiNOCO-AP-700-55-e6-e1</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <radio index="1">
         <antenna />
         <antenna_gain />
         <channel>1</channel>
         <display_channel>1</display_channel>
         <display_enabled>false</display_enabled>
         <display_transmit_power>22.5 dBm</display_transmit_power>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <operational_mode>g</operational_mode>
         <radio_interface>1</radio_interface>
         <radio_mac>00:20:A6:55:E6:E0</radio_mac>
         <radio_type>g</radio_type>
         <transmit_power>100%</transmit_power>
      </radio>
      <reboot_count>2</reboot_count>
      <serial_number>04UT43570051</serial_number>
      <snmp_uptime>0</snmp_uptime>
      <ssid>proxim_test</ssid>
      <syscontact />
      <syslocation />
      <upstream_device_id>3648</upstream_device_id>
      <upstream_port_index>16</upstream_port_index>
   </ap>
   <ap id="3648">
      <controller_id>9</controller_id>
      <device_category>thin_ap</device_category>
      <firmware>4.0.155.0</firmware>
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <lan_ip>10.51.1.16</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:0B:85:62:64:70</lan_mac>
      <mfgr>Cisco</mfgr>
      <model id="94">Aironet 1030 LWAPP</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>aironet-1030-5</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <radio index="1">
         <antenna>Enabled</antenna>
         <antenna_gain>15</antenna_gain>
         <antenna_type>internal</antenna_type>
         <channel>1</channel>
         <display_channel>1</display_channel>
         <display_enabled>false</display_enabled>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <operational_mode>g</operational_mode>
         <radio_interface>1</radio_interface>
         <radio_mac>00:0B:85:62:64:70</radio_mac>
         <radio_role>ap</radio_role>
         <radio_type>g</radio_type>
         <transmit_power>7 dBm</transmit_power>
      </radio>
      <radio index="2">
         <antenna>Side B</antenna>
         <antenna_gain />
         <antenna_type>external</antenna_type>
         <channel>56</channel>
         <display_channel>56</display_channel>
         <display_enabled>true</display_enabled>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <operational_mode>a</operational_mode>
         <radio_interface>2</radio_interface>
         <radio_mac>00:0B:85:62:64:70</radio_mac>
         <radio_role>ap</radio_role>
         <radio_type>abg</radio_type>
         <transmit_power>5 dBm</transmit_power>
      </radio>
      <syscontact>dev team</syscontact>
      <syscontact>Second shelf from bottom</syscontact>
      <upstream_device_id />
      <upstream_port_index />
   </ap>
   <ap id="2418">
      <device_category>controller</device_category>
      <firmware>6.1.1.1</firmware>
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <lan_ip>10.51.3.119</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:0B:86:61:16:5C</lan_mac>
      <mfgr>Aruba</mfgr>
      <model id="226">3200</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>Aruba3200-119</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <serial_number>AC0000479</serial_number>
      <syscontact>qa team</syscontact>
      <syslocation>Viewonly</syslocation>
      <upstream_device_id />
      <upstream_port_index />
   </ap>
   <ap id="1437">
      <device_category>switch</device_category>
      <firmware>12.2(25)SEE4</firmware>
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <lan_ip>10.51.0.26</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:18:18:9E:C9:40</lan_mac>
      <mfgr>Cisco</mfgr>
      <model id="319">Catalyst 3560-24PS-S</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>switch7</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <serial_number>CAT10205436</serial_number>
      <syscontact />
      <syslocation>server room</syslocation>
      <upstream_device_id />
      <upstream_port_index />
   </ap>
</amp:amp_ap_list>
```

Comment: The full code is here https://github.com/nxfxn/airwave-api-python/blob/master/airwaveApi.py. I just added an extra element called Group and would like to filter on that element.  At the moment all the group categories return, I only need the group 'Access Points'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<amp:amp_ap_list xmlns:amp="http://www.airwave.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.airwave.com amp_ap_list.xsd">
   <ap id="79">
      <altitude>0</altitude>
      <device_category>fat_ap</device_category>
      <client_count>1</client_count>
      <firmware>3.2.0</firmware>
      <fqdn />
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <is_remote_ap>true</is_remote_ap>
      <remote_outer_ip>10.1.1.1</remote_outer_ip>
      <remote_lan_ip>20.20.20.20</remote_lan_ip>
      <lan_ip>10.51.1.191</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:20:A6:55:E6:E1</lan_mac>
      <last_contacted>1350379063</last_contacted>
      <last_reboot>1343644897</last_reboot>
      <mfgr>Proxim</mfgr>
      <model id="44">AP-700</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>ORiNOCO-AP-700-55-e6-e1</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <radio index="1">
         <antenna />
         <antenna_gain />
         <channel>1</channel>
         <display_channel>1</display_channel>
         <display_enabled>false</display_enabled>
         <display_transmit_power>22.5 dBm</display_transmit_power>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <operational_mode>g</operational_mode>
         <radio_interface>1</radio_interface>
         <radio_mac>00:20:A6:55:E6:E0</radio_mac>
         <radio_type>g</radio_type>
         <transmit_power>100%</transmit_power>
      </radio>
      <reboot_count>2</reboot_count>
      <serial_number>04UT43570051</serial_number>
      <snmp_uptime>0</snmp_uptime>
      <ssid>proxim_test</ssid>
      <syscontact />
      <syslocation />
      <upstream_device_id>3648</upstream_device_id>
      <upstream_port_index>16</upstream_port_index>
   </ap>
   <ap id="3648">
      <controller_id>9</controller_id>
      <device_category>thin_ap</device_category>
      <firmware>4.0.155.0</firmware>
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <lan_ip>10.51.1.16</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:0B:85:62:64:70</lan_mac>
      <mfgr>Cisco</mfgr>
      <model id="94">Aironet 1030 LWAPP</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>aironet-1030-5</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <radio index="1">
         <antenna>Enabled</antenna>
         <antenna_gain>15</antenna_gain>
         <antenna_type>internal</antenna_type>
         <channel>1</channel>
         <display_channel>1</display_channel>
         <display_enabled>false</display_enabled>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <operational_mode>g</operational_mode>
         <radio_interface>1</radio_interface>
         <radio_mac>00:0B:85:62:64:70</radio_mac>
         <radio_role>ap</radio_role>
         <radio_type>g</radio_type>
         <transmit_power>7 dBm</transmit_power>
      </radio>
      <radio index="2">
         <antenna>Side B</antenna>
         <antenna_gain />
         <antenna_type>external</antenna_type>
         <channel>56</channel>
         <display_channel>56</display_channel>
         <display_enabled>true</display_enabled>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <operational_mode>a</operational_mode>
         <radio_interface>2</radio_interface>
         <radio_mac>00:0B:85:62:64:70</radio_mac>
         <radio_role>ap</radio_role>
         <radio_type>abg</radio_type>
         <transmit_power>5 dBm</transmit_power>
      </radio>
      <syscontact>dev team</syscontact>
      <syscontact>Second shelf from bottom</syscontact>
      <upstream_device_id />
      <upstream_port_index />
   </ap>
   <ap id="2418">
      <device_category>controller</device_category>
      <firmware>6.1.1.1</firmware>
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <lan_ip>10.51.3.119</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:0B:86:61:16:5C</lan_mac>
      <mfgr>Aruba</mfgr>
      <model id="226">3200</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>Aruba3200-119</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <serial_number>AC0000479</serial_number>
      <syscontact>qa team</syscontact>
      <syslocation>Viewonly</syslocation>
      <upstream_device_id />
      <upstream_port_index />
   </ap>
   <ap id="1437">
      <device_category>switch</device_category>
      <firmware>12.2(25)SEE4</firmware>
      <group id="1">Access Points</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <lan_ip>10.51.0.26</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:18:18:9E:C9:40</lan_mac>
      <mfgr>Cisco</mfgr>
      <model id="319">Catalyst 3560-24PS-S</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>switch7</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <serial_number>CAT10205436</serial_number>
      <syscontact />
      <syslocation>server room</syslocation>
      <upstream_device_id />
      <upstream_port_index />
   </ap>
     <ap id="143347">
      <device_category>switch</device_category>
      <firmware>12.2(25)SEE4</firmware>
      <group id="1">Other Group Name</group>
      <is_up>true</is_up>
      <lan_ip>10.51.0.26</lan_ip>
      <lan_mac>00:18:18:9E:C9:40</lan_mac>
      <mfgr>Cisco</mfgr>
      <model id="319">Catalyst 3560-24PS-S</model>
      <monitor_only>true</monitor_only>
      <name>switch7</name>
      <operating_mode>ap</operating_mode>
      <planned_maintenance_mode>false</planned_maintenance_mode>
      <serial_number>CAT10205436</serial_number>
      <syscontact />
      <syslocation>server room</syslocation>
      <upstream_device_id />
      <upstream_port_index />
   </ap>
</amp:amp_ap_list>'''

# Add more properties if you wish
INTERESTING_PROPERTIES = {'lan_ip', 'lan_mac', 'name'}

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
ap_access_points = [element for element in root.findall('.//ap') if element.find('./group').text == 'Access Points']
for ap in ap_access_points:
    print('ap: {}'.format(ap.attrib['id']))
    for child in list(ap):
        if child.tag in INTERESTING_PROPERTIES:
            print('\t{} --> {}'.format(child.tag, child.text))
```

output

```
ap: 79
    lan_ip --> 10.51.1.191
    lan_mac --> 00:20:A6:55:E6:E1
    name --> ORiNOCO-AP-700-55-e6-e1
ap: 3648
    lan_ip --> 10.51.1.16
    lan_mac --> 00:0B:85:62:64:70
    name --> aironet-1030-5
ap: 2418
    lan_ip --> 10.51.3.119
    lan_mac --> 00:0B:86:61:16:5C
    name --> Aruba3200-119
ap: 1437
    lan_ip --> 10.51.0.26
    lan_mac --> 00:18:18:9E:C9:40
    name --> switch7
```

Comment: That is an interesting way to do this.  Thank you.